# DjangoAdmin form with 1:N selection wont save object

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I was looking for a way to assign one, or more, already existing objects to the current one, while creating in the add section. Something like InLine but I do not want to create them, only select and assign.

Two example models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

So while creating `Location` in Django Admin, I want to be able to assign 1-N existing `Devices`.

I found a way to do so, with a custom `Form`

Here is my custom Form inside `admin.py`

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'

    devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Device.objects.all()) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['devices'].initial = self.instance.device_set.all()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        self.fields['devices'].initial.update(location=None)
        self.cleaned_data['devices'].update(location=instance)
        return instance

@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LocationForm
```

That works fine as long as I dont save the `Location` object. Here is a picture of how it looks in django admin.
[image: Django Admin One to Many]

However when I try to save the Location, I got the following error:

```
 File "admin.py", line 21, in save
    api          |     self.cleaned_data['devices'].update(location=instance)
    api          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 692, in update
    api          |     rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
    api          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1378, in execute_sql
    api          |     cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
    api          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    api          |     sql, params = self.as_sql()
    api          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in as_sql
    api          |     val.prepare_database_save(field),
    api          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 932, in prepare_database_save
    api          |     raise ValueError("Unsaved model instance %r cannot be used in an ORM query." % self)
    api          | ValueError: Unsaved model instance <Location: Test Project> cannot be used in an ORM query.
```

I've tried manually saving the object in the save method but that didn't work either, I'm running out of ideas since I don't really know why it is not saving at all. I though the save method from the superclass would be enough but apparently that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it, after reading my question for like seven times.

At first line of the log it says `self.cleaned_data['devices'].update(location=instance)` so clearly the `instance` is the thing that is not saved and thus cannot be used as a query parameter, so I edited my Form's save method like this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(LocationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        self.fields['devices'].initial.update(location=None)
        instance.save()
        self.cleaned_data['devices'].update(location=instance)        
        return instance
```

And it is working.